# How to scrape total search results using Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and web scraping but I am really interested. What I want to do is to extract the total number of search results per day.

If you open it, you will see here:

Used Cars for Sale 
Results 1 - 20 of 30,376

What I want is only the number 30,376. Is there any way to extract it on a daily basis automatically and save it to an excel file please? I have played around some packages in Python but all I got is error messages and something not relevant like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

base_url = "..."

def make_soup(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    return BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

make_soup(base_url)
```

Can someone show me how to extract that particular number please? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers. They all worked! My another question is that, I need to exact that number together with that day's date to an existing excel file. This file already have numbers that I extracted manually over the past few months. The table has 2 columns: date, number. Is it possible to do this please? Thanks again!

Comment: Where are you going to get the Date from? Does the HTML DOM object contains the Date as well?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for asking! I checked the HTML but didn't see any date info. So does that mean it is not possible to get the date? If not, that's ok, but how do I save the output number into my existing excel file please? I wanna make it go under the number column if possible :) Thanks again!

Comment: Which date do you want to enter in the excel? The date on which you run the python script or some other date?

Comment: The date I run the python script. Ideally I will need to automate the extraction so it can be done daily

Comment: Ok. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Test the code before running it on your file. Maybe make a copy of the file and then run it on the copied file. So that you don't loose your data if something crashes. I have tested it on my side, its working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one way through `requests` module and `soup.select` function.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = "http://www.autotrader.co.nz/used-cars-for-sale"

def make_soup(url):
    html = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    txt = soup.select('#result-header .result-count')[0].text
    print txt.split()[-1]

make_soup(base_url)
```

`soup.select` accepts an css selector as argument. This `#result-header .result-count` selector means find the element having `result-count` class which was inside an element having `result-header` as id.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

base_url = "http://www.autotrader.co.nz/used-cars-for-sale"
a = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url).content).select('div#result-header p.result-count')[0].text
num = re.search('([\w,]+)$',a)
print int(num.groups(1)[0].replace(',',''))
```

Output:

```
30378
```

Will get any other number also which is at the end of the statement.

---

## Appending new rows to an Existing Excel File

Script to append today's date and the extracted number to existing excel file:

**!!!Important!!!:** Don't run this code directly on your main file. Instead make a copy of it first and run on that file. If it works properly then you can run it on your main file. **I'm not responsible if you loose your data :)**

```
import openpyxl
import datetime

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/home/yusuf/Desktop/data.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

a = sheet.get_highest_row()
sheet.cell(row=a,column=0).value=datetime.date.today()
sheet.cell(row=a,column=1).value=30378 # use a variable here from the above (previous) code. 

wb.save('/home/yusuf/Desktop/data.xlsx')
```

Comment: @Sunshine Consider accepting the best answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks again Mohammad:)

Comment: @Sunshine If it solved your problem then consider clicking on the  "Check Mark" on the left of answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

base_url = "http://www.autotrader.co.nz/used-cars-for-sale"
html = urlopen(base_url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

result_count = soup.find(class_="result-count").text.split('of ')[-1]

print(result_count)
```

out:

```
30,376
```